# How to reinstall/uninstall Foxit Reader in Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstallation, ubuntu-16.04, foxit, foxit-reader

I have installed Foxit Reader via foxit link on the web, but it seems the installation is faulty. Each time I try to use foxit, it shows ".../opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/configtoolbar.xml fail!" and the toolbal display of foxit reader is corrupted. I want to remove foxit via software center, but did not work, try to reinstall foxit, it hangs there forever. Anyone knows how to fix this? I would like to remove it and reinstall a clean copy.

Comment: Same problem here. How to uninstall foxit is all over the place.
I tried 
`sudo ./maintenancetool.sh`
with the feedback 
`./maintenancetool.sh: 40: /home/mila/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/./maintenancetool: not found`
and 
`sudo ./Uninstall.desktop`
with a bunch of errors that do not fit here.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution. It seems that the application try to write on the configtoolbar.xml file, but doesn't have write permission.
Just go to the file location, run

```
sudo chmod 666 configtoolbar.xml
```

and restart Foxit-Reader, then the error message will be gone, and the toolbar display will no longer be corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

About installation:

You should install Foxit Reader as regular user, not root. Then no configtoolbar.xml problem.

About uninstallation:

You can enter the foxitreader directory and execute the bash script maintenancetool.sh. If you install it as root, the default directory is /opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader.